# ¿Cómo saber si un double tiene punto flotante?

Tags: c#

Si utilizo el método `Math.Sqrt()` me devuelve un `double`. Quiero saber si ese `double` no tiene punto flotante, o sea, es un número sin coma.

Answer (score 11):

Propongo tres formas:

- Réstale su parte entera y evalúa si el resultado es 0:

  ```
  bool tieneParteDecimal(double d) {
      return (d - ((long)d) != 0;
  }
  ```
- Utiliza `Math#Floor` y evalúa si son iguales:

  ```
  bool tieneParteDecimal (double d) {
      return d != Math.Floor(d);
  }
  ```
- De la respuesta aceptada en [How to determine if a decimal/double is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751597/1065197), evalúa su módulo contra 1:

  ```
  bool tieneParteDecimal (double d) {
      return d % 1 != 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

En `C#` comúnmente se usa :

```
bool noPuntoFlotante (double d) {
    return d % 1 == 0;
}
```

Ya que como sabemos `numero % 1 == 0` es la forma para comprobar si hay algo más allá del punto decimal.

Ejemplos:

```
  decimal d = 4.2M;
  Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0); // devuelve falso.
  d = 5.0M;
  Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0); // devuelve verdadero.
  d = 23.3M;
  Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0); // devuelve falso.
```